# How to create Full-text search index in MySQL AWS Aurora DB InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, amazon-aurora

While trying to add full-text index on the table I am getting below error.

> Error Code: 1214. The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

And while trying to create a table with MyTSAM engine I am getting below warning message.

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1266 Using storage engine InnoDB for
>   table

Answer (score 5):

AWS Aurora supports full text indexing. We're using it with InnoDb (MySQL 5.7) tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE full_search_indexes (
  code varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  entity_type varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  full_text text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  time_created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  time_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (code,entity_type),
  FULLTEXT KEY full_text (full_text)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Aurora supports full text indexing natively. You may want to enable binlogs and stream that out to an elastic search cluster that you manage on your own. As for the second error, Aurora supports only the InnoDB storage engine. Other engine types are not supported.

Comment: May I ask whether the Postgres-compatible version of Aurora supports FTS or not?